# Detectar cuando se escribe algo en la consola javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, cmd, terminal, línea-de-comandos

lo que quiero hacer no se si funciona.

Tengo un script en javascript que ejecuta node.js, lo que quiero es que mientras el programa se está ejecutando si escribo `/hola` me responda con un `hola`. He probado con

```
console.addEventListener(nombreEvento, function(a) {
  console.log(a);
});
```

pero no funciona.

Comment: Tienes que ***mostrarnos el código*** si pretendes que encontremos el error. Puedes leer más información sobre cómo hacer una pregunta correcta en [ask] y haciendo el [tour]

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido, la consola es un objeto no leíble, es decir que puedes interactuar con este objeto pero no podrás saber que se está escribiendo

Comment: el (seudo)código está implícito en la pregunta, pero no hay error concreto. Está preguntando si existe un método.

Comment: Creo que JS no tiene control sobre eso.. pero si puedes ejecutar funciones como decir("hola") y que tal función conteste por consola.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

para que no nos confundamos, entiendo que en tu pregunta "la Consola" se refiere a la línea de comando y no a la instancia `console` con que haces, por ejemplo, `console.log`. Ambas se relacionan en que al llamar a `console.log` la salida se ve en la línea de comando.

la instancia `console` en nodejs según el método escribe a `process.stdout`  y `process.stderr`. Ambos son un tipo de [Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) al cual puedes escribir, pero no siempre puedes leer de él. [Hay un feature request en nodejs desde el 2016 sobre eso](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8033).

Hay [Paquetes como tslog que interceptan la consola](https://tslog.js.org/#/README?id=highlights) con un hack bien frágil del tipo

```
const originalConsoleLog = console.log;

console.log = (...args) => {
  hacerAlgoConArgs(...args);
  originalConsoleLog(...args);
});
```

> si escribo /hola me responda con un hola

De esta parte entiendo que en realidad quieres recibir el ingreso de texto por línea de comando y no interceptar la salida *hacia* la consola. Ese texto que escribes va al stream [process.stdin](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) del cual sí es trivial detectar input.

```
process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
  let partialText = '',
      chunk;
  while (null !== (chunk = process.stdin.read())) {
    partialText += chunk;
  }
  const instruccion = partialText.toString('utf8').trim();

  console.log(`Escribiste "${instruccion}"`);
});

require('net').createServer().listen();
```

Necesitas mantener el proceso andando para que puedas probarlo así que levanté un server dummy que se queda escuchando hasta que interrumpes el proceso.

Comment: Gracias. me funciono!